# How to efficiently copy a std::string into a vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

I have a string

```
std::string s = "Stack Overflow";
```

That I need to copy into a vector.
This is how I am doing it

```
std::vector<char> v;
v.reserve(s.length()+1);
for(std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
{
    v.push_back( *it );
}
v.push_back( '\0' );
```

But I hear range operation are more efficient. So I am thinking something like this

```
std::vector<char> v( s.begin(), s.end());
v.push_back('\0');
```

But is this better in this case? What about the potential re-allocation when inserting '\0'?
Another approach I am thinking is this

```
std::vector<char> v(s.length()+1);
std::strcpy(&v[0],s.c_str());
```

Perhaps fast but potentially unsafe? 
EDIT
Has to be a null terminated string that can be used ( read/write ) inside a C function

Comment: I would use the last one with strncopy. But this is only my opinion.

Comment: Where does the string come from? How is the resulting vector being used? Is it necessary to include the terminating 0? Can you just use the string as the container instead of needing a vector at all?

Comment: @tenfour The resulting vector is to be passed to a c function in a non-const fashion i.e. read/write

Comment: This is so wrong, nobody thought to invent an interface that would do it smoothly

Comment: @DeadMG: in my experience, the interface that would do it smoothly, that is to say the C++ wrapper around some C library or other, is where this sort of construct is most needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If* you really need a vector (e.g. because your C function modifies the string content), then the following should give you what you want, in one line:

```
std::vector<char> v(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.length() + 1);
```

Since `c_str()` returns a null-terminated string, you can just copy it whole into the vector.

However, I’m not actually sure how optimised this constructor is. I *do* know that `std::copy` is as optimised as it gets, so perhaps (measure!) the following is faster:

```
std::vector<char> v(s.length() + 1);
std::copy(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.length() + 1, v.begin());
```

If the C function doesn’t modify the string, just pass `c_str()` directly, and cast away const-ness. This is safe, *as long as* the C function only reads from the string.

Comment: "I do know that std::copy is as optimised as it gets" - or if there's doubt about the QOI of a particular standard template library, then `memcpy` would do as well and has an even better chance of being fiendishly optimized.

Comment: @Steve Ugh. Juck! Don’t like low-level C functions where C++ algorithms are conceptually so much cleaner, and fundamentally able to optimise more due to type information. There isn’t a single case where `memcpy` should be able to perform better (except for the point about overlapping memory).

Comment: @Konrad: I suppose there should never be "doubt" about QOI of the standard `std::copy`, since you can just look at the code and/or profile it to be sure. I think that "std::copy is as optimised as it gets" is either the statement of someone who has hand-checked every C++ implementation in the world, or a guess ;-p I wouldn't put it past some platform somewhere to have a pretty trivial `std::copy` implementation, not specialized for char, and an optimizer that can't make up for that. In which case I maintain the thing to do is check whether `memcpy` is any better.

Comment: In summary, I'm not talking about whether `std::copy` *should* be optimized (of course it should - everything should be). I'm just noting what to try next if it isn't.

Comment: @Steve Well, restricting the statement to the major compiler / library vendors (GCC, ICC, VC++) I can indeed state this quite confidently. Once you venture into esoteric compilers / platforms, all bets are off in general. However, many modern libraries and applications just *rely* on the QOI of the standard library algorithms.

Comment: @Konrad: well, if you're going to start making realistic assumptions, then we can probably just use the fact that string storage is contiguous and nul-terminated. Pass `&s[0]` to the mystery C function, and be sure that if that function threatens to make the string any shorter, that you `resize()` it afterwards down to the position of the first nul character. Saves any copies.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph If the vector is pre-declared i.e. you have no opportunity to initialize it with s.length()+1 would you call v.resize() or v.reserve() or both before invoking std::copy?

Comment: @molita: call `resize`. You are not allowed to access indexes which have been reserved but which are beyond the current size of the vector.

Comment: I don't see why you should doubt the efficiency of the iterator range constructor. In the second case you'll first initialize it all to '\0' (again using a "dubious" vector constructor implementation), why should that be any better?

Comment: @UncleBens Because I know that `std::copy` is extremely optimised, and in particular for this case. I don’t know whether the `vector` constructor is. Granted, it should usually just use `std::copy` or something equivalent (with move rather than copy) internally.

Comment: With G++, all the vector's  iterator pair constructor ends up doing is calling std::copy eventually. If everybody knows it's so good, why would the library implementation choose something poorer? - And you still can't trust the vector to fill the buffer with nulls fast.

Comment: what do you want to do anyway with the vector of characters? 
if you want to put it into a (non modifying) C function just cast away the const from s.c_str() ?

Comment: @Alex You said it: *non* modifying. This is, by the way, what I said in my answer. But as soon as the C function modifies the string buffer, a vector of chars is the best portable solution.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, you don't need vector of `char`, as `std::string` pretty much is a container of `char`. `std::string` also have `begin` and `end` functions. And it also have `c_str()` function which returns the *c-string* which you can pass to any function which expects `const char*`, such as this:

```
void f(const char* str); //c-function

std::string s="some string";
f(s.c_str());
```

So why would you ever need `std::vector<char>`?

In my opinion, `vector<char>` is a very very rare need but if I ever need it, I would probably write this:

```
std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());
```

And to me, `v.push_back('\0')` doesn't make much sense. There is no such requirement on vector to have the last element as `'\0'` if the `value_type` is `char`.

Alright, as you said, `std::string::c_str()` returns `const char*`, and the c-function needs a non-const `char*` , then you can use `std::vector` because you want to take advantage of RAII which vector implements:

```
void g(char* s); //c-function

std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());
s.push_back('\0');

g(&v[0]);
```

which seems fine to me. But RAII is all that you need, then you've other option as well:

```
{
  std::vector<char> memory(s.size()+1);
  char *str = &memory[0]; //gets the memory!
  std::strcpy(str, s.c_str());

  g(str);
  //....

} //<--- memory is destroyed here.
```

Use `std::strcpy`, `std::memcpy` or `std::copy` whichever is fast, as I cannot say which one is ***necessarily*** fast, without profiling.

Comment: How would a C function recognize it as a null terminated string?

Comment: @molita: You did not mention that requirement.

Comment: @molita: You can simply pass `s.c_str()`.

Comment: Sorry, -1. You spend most of your answer explaining that the vector isn't necessary. Then you admit that it might be necessary, but you don't advance on what's already in the question, just express an unsupported preference for one of the two possibilities

Comment: @Steve: The question has been edited. Previously, he didn't mention why he need it. Also, I didn't say `the vector isn't necessary`. I said, its very rare need.

Comment: -1 removed since you've offered an alternative not mentioned in the question. I don't think it should matter why it's needed -- comments are for telling people they shouldn't be asking the question they're asking, not answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `std::strcpy(&v[0],s.c_str());` is a good choice. I think `c_str()` is allowed to re-allocate.

If you somehow "need" the `\0` for dealing with C-APIs, then rely on `string::c_str()` to provide it to you, on request. In dont think that you need to put it into a vector-of-char, most things you can do with the string itself like with a vector.

**Update**:

If you make sure your vector gets initialized with `0`s, you can circumvent the call to `c_str` by using `strncopy`:

```
std::vector<char> v(s.length()+1, 0);  // added '0'
std::strncpy(&v[0],&s[0],s.length());  // no c_str()
```

Comment: I agree that it’s not a good choice but I don’t see how `c_str()` doing a re-allocation is important. The code is still well-defined.

Comment: yes, right, well defined. I just meant, that he might want to prevent internal re-allocations for performance reasons. Wait, I update my answer...

Comment: How would constructing a vector with 0's and **then** copy the string into it be any better than letting the vector constructor copy the string?

Comment: @Bo: No I would not prefer this solution. I just wanted to point out the `strncpy` way. I +1'd Konrads answer :-)