# How to efficiently copy a std::vector<char> to a std::string

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

This question is a flip side of this [How to efficiently copy a std::string into a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378087/how-to-efficiently-copy-a-stdstring-into-a-vector) 
I typically copy the vector this way ( null terminated string )

```
std::string s((char*)&v[0]);
```

or ( if the string has already been declared ) like this

```
s = (char*)&v[0];
```

It gets the job done but perhaps there are better ways.
**EDIT**
C-style casts are ugly, I am told so what about this

```
s = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vo[0]);
```

Comment: No cast necessary. &v[0] yields a char*; std::string has a constructor that takes const char*; converting char* to const char* does not require a cast.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
std::string s( &v[ 0 ] );
```

generates less than half the number of lines of assembly code in Visual C++ 2005 as

```
std::string s( v.begin(), v.end() );
```

Comment: I was waiting for a response like this. So you are saying the answer with most votes does not actually improve that much on what am currently doing. In terms of efficiency anyway

Comment: @karimjee: The number of lines of assembly generated is one concrete measure of efficiency. By this measure, what you're already doing is most efficient. I suspect that s( &v[0], v.length() ) may be more efficient (as well as safer), but I'm away from my Windows machine at the moment...

Comment: @karimjee: My suspicion was wrong; s( &v[0] ) and s( &v[0], v.size() ) generate the same number of lines of assembly in VS 2005. BTW, if you like my answer, please upvote. If this is the answer you were looking for, please accept it.

Comment: The number of lines of generated assembly might be concrete, but it is rarely any real use. In the example above I would still use the the second version as it will be more efficient (as it already knows the size of the string and can pre-allocate the space).

Comment: @karimjee: Accepting a bad answer because they agree with you is not really a good idea. Unless the people that answer have obviously missed something in your question then one the higher (not necessarily the top) voted answers should be accepted (but the top answer here has an order of magnitude more votes than the other answers).

Comment: @Tux-D: The last time I checked, `execution_time = #_instructions_executed * cycles_per_instruction * clock_cycle_time` so something that takes fewer instructions will be execute more quickly, and be more efficient by that measure. Remember [Larry's Rule of Software Engineering #1: "Every software engineer should know roughly what assembly language their code generates."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/04/06/108686.aspx)

Comment: @Gnawme: If it was only that simple. But things like memory allocation invoke thousands of extra instructions as routines from the standard library are called. Since the second version will only try to allocate memory once and the first version will try and allocate memory dependent on the size of the string (or first calculate the size of the string by running through the whole string). The second one can be an order of magnitude faster than the first one (depending on the string being copied). Raw instruction count is irrelevant if you are calling subroutines (or looping).

Comment: Also your formula is overly simple as different instructions will take different number of cycles, branches can invalidate the predictive scheduling used by modern processors. Also I think that rule is irrelevant in today super optimizing compilers. If you understand all the optimizations your compiler is doing during code generation then you are no longer writing code but writing compilers (or should be). Also if you really knew the rule you would use the second version.

Comment: Visual Studio 2005, Release mode, /O2 -- `std::string onoc( &ono[ 0 ], ono.size() );`: 19 lines of assembly, 1 constructor call `std::string onos( ono.begin(), ono.end() );`: 30 lines of assembly, 2 constructor calls. Paying attention to the code your design and coding decisions generate, and consequences of your compiler's optimizations, is just part of being a professional coder. (Especially in the embedded/mobile space.)

Comment: I profiled it. The method you want is `::std::string s(vec.data(), vec.size());`. That is the fastest method of initializing a string from a vector with gcc-4.6. It is far, far faster than using an iterator pair.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Nice. Unfortunately, there's no vector::data() in C++03, but I would guess &vec[0] isn't any slower, and is likely what data() does under the hood.

Comment: @Gnawme: Yes. When you pass in the size you get much better code (and I would go with that as a good answer). **But** that's not what we were taking about above as your question still shows.

Answer (score 15):

Just use the iterator constructor:

```
std::string s(v.begin(), v.end());
```

(*Edit*): Or use the char-pointer-plus-size constructor:

```
std::string s(v.data(), v.size());   // or &v[0]
```

If your string is null-terminated and you want to omit the terminator, then use a `char*`-constructor:

```
std::string s(v.data());             // or &v[0]
```

*Update:* As @Dave says, you can use the same syntax for [assigning](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/) to an existing string:

```
s.assign(v.begin(), v.end());
s.assign(v.data(), v.size());  // pointer plus size
s.assign(v.data());            // null-terminated
```

Comment: What if the string is pre-declared, e.g. as a member variable. i.e. you have no opportunity to call the constructor

Comment: @kairmjee Use  the `assign` member function, which can take the same arguments as the constructor.

Comment: @Dave Can you improve on this answer then, because that use case in important

Comment: I added the assignment syntax. Thanks, Dave!

Comment: Note that the null-terminated case here has worse performance, as the std::string constructor must scan the string once to identify its length before copying it.

Comment: @bdonlan: Indeed. If you know the size, the iterator construction or the char-pointer-plus-size is the better choice.

Comment: @Kerrek SB You lost me here. The iterator construction is better if you know the size? But I don't see any call to size in your answer.

Comment: As a note, `v.data()` isn't standard unless you're using C++11.

Comment: But is this efficient? Will this ultimately result in some variant of `memcpy` being emitted by the compiler? I'm not so sure. Are there overloads that recognize when the constructor or `assign` is being given random access iterators that support the concept of finding the distance between them? Because otherwise there is no way for those functions to know the number of characters before copying, which in turn requires all the re-allocation logic to come into play, which is not very efficient. And, of course, the null terminated case certainly can't do this.

Comment: I double-checked. Constructing from iterators is very definitely not efficient for exactly the reason I gave. At least not with g++ 4.6.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I see. Well, it could have been, given that the iterators are random-access and the size is in fact known ahead of time, so I guess that's a weakness of the implementation... You could try `std::string(v.data(), v.size())` to see if that's faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
s.resize( v.size() );
std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), s.begin() );
```

You may as why... because once those damn compiler creators understand the power of standarization, this method will be way faster than any other...

And on a more serious note:

```
std::string( (char*)v.data(), v.size() );
s.assign( (char*)v.data(), v.size() );
```

... might be safer, without loosing efficiency.

Comment: The `::std::copy` method will not work unless you've called `s.resize();` first.

Comment: @Kornel Your std::copy answer is very good in my view. How about you make that the 'serious' one?

Comment: Your answer is better because it doesn't rely on the constructor or assign knowing that you're feeding them random access iterators. Though C style casts are still ugly.

Comment: The `copy` option generates the most obviously efficient code. The others result in a call to a function that is presumably efficient.

Comment: I ran some profiling and tested with vectors big and small. Constructing or copying from `.data()` + `v.size()` was the fastest option in all cases. Constructing from a begin/end iterator pair was the slowest. The first method you list, the one where you're being silly is the second slowest, but that's because `.resize` has to initialize everything first.